# Having Trouble ReInstalling macOS

Tags: macos

We have Apple M1 MacBook Airs at our school.  I had to factory reset one and sent a command from Mosyle Manager to Erase the device.

After the device erased, I couldn't reinstall macOS Big Sur. Looking at the recovery screen, when trying to reinstall macOS, there is no disk to click.

When I go to disk utility, I see:
Apple SSD AP0128Q Media
Apple Disk Image Media
Container Disk4
macOS Base System

Running first aid on everything gives no errors.

If I try to erase Apple SSD Media, it shows the error message:
"The volume on disk0 couldn't be unmounted because it is in use by process 0 (kernel)
Couldn't open device"

If I try to partition, it says "Couldn't open device".

Any help would be appreciated, I cannot seem to figure this out.
Thank you.

[image: Running diskutil list from terminal]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to redownload macOS Big Sur over wifi using macOS Recovery mode. Boot up your Mac into Recovery mode, and then reinstall Big Sur. Here's the official Apple page for how to reinstall macOS Big Sur on an Apple Silicon Mac: [Use macOS Recovery on a Mac with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/11.0/mac/11.0).

Comment: When I try to do that, there is no disk available to select to install macOS.